# Combining data for regression in R

Tags: r

I am doing my thesis on the stock performance after controlling fama-french model.
The concept is that I have several stocks in my portfolio with monthly return on the column. (each stock may start from/end in different period.) I would like to have an simple average return representing the data on that day. For example, on 1997/08/29, the return should be (-0.02787+0.12)/2. After creating the new data set (y), I will run linear regression with fama-french model(x).

So my question is:
(1) how can I create a new data set with average return?
(2) How to do linear regression? (I think I can figure this out by finding material online, but I would be grateful if you could give me some assistance)

thank you so much

I am new to R...

[image]

Comment: For aggregating you would use `aggregate` function and `lm` or `glm` or many other functions for various types of regressions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, as you say, you will figure out linear regression yourself, here's an answer to question #1:

To calculate the (arithmetic) average of `Return` by `Date`, use, for example, `tapply`:

```
tapply(df$Return, df$Date, mean)

  19970630   19970731   19970829   19970930 
-1.4805676 -0.2102363 -0.6145203 -0.9200052
```

Data:

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c(19970630,19970731,19970829,19970930,19970731,19970829),
  Ticker = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 2)),
  Return = rnorm(6)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is also `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Return ~ Date, df, mean)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c(19970630,19970731,19970829,19970930,19970731,19970829),
  Ticker = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 2)),
  Return = rnorm(6)
)
```